# Show / Hide a div depending on radio button selection

Tags: html, jquery, radio-button

Im trying to work out a basic script to show/hide DIVs depending on what radio buttons are selected. Im new to scripting so not really that sure of what I'm doing... If could be pointed in the right direction that would be great.

At them moment a DIV shows up if I click on the YES answer (and I realise I have duplicate IDs at the moment - still trying to work out the script and I can figure out how to make it work when I change them to a class)

So what I want is a bunch of questions with three answer choices - YES, NO and UNSURE. There will be three hidden DIVs under the questions. After an answer has been placed in every question one of the three divs will show.

All YES answers -

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="question-1">
 <p>Question one...</p>
 <input id="yes" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
 <input name="test" type="radio" />No
 <input name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<form id="question-2">
 <p>Question two...</p>
 <input id="yes" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
 <input name="test" type="radio" />No
 <input name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<form id="question-3">
 <p>Question three...</p>
 <input id="yes" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
 <input name="test" type="radio" />No
 <input name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<div id="show-me-1" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'Yes'</div>
<div id="show-me-2" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are a combination of 'Yes' 'No' and 'Unsure'</div>
<div id="show-me-3" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'No'</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
       if($(this).attr('id') == 'yes') {
            $('#show-me-1').show();           
       }

       else {
            $('#show-me-1').hide();   
       }
   });
}); 
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

show-me-1
A combination of answers - show-me-2
All NO answers - show-me-3

I also need a button to clear all the answers and hide the div again - but not sure how to do that.

Comment: please tell when you want to show the hide divisions

Comment: Please check the below solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, one question... Why are you using one form for each question? If there's no reason for that, you better put one form and change the "name" value of each set of radio buttons. First, I've cleaned out your HTML a little bit...

```
<form id="questions">
    <p class="question-title">Question one...</p>
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <p class="question-title">Question two...</p>
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <p class="question-title">Question three...</p>
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure
</form>

<div id="show-me-1" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'Yes'</div>
<div id="show-me-2" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are a combination of 'Yes' 'No' and 'Unsure'</div>
<div id="show-me-3" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'No'</div>
```

One posible solution for your problem is to set one specific weight to each response, so when all questions are answered, you can sum the results and know if all are Yes, all No or a mix. You could set the weight using the "value" attribute of the radio button, but I prefer to create an independent data field, so you can use "value" for some info sended to with the form.

So here you have a posible way to do it...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

    var nQuestions = $('p.question-title').length;
    var $checkedItems = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if($checkedItems.length == nQuestions) {  // All answered

      var sum = 0;
      $checkedItems.each(function() {
          sum += Number($(this).data('weight'));
      });

      $('div.result').hide();
      if(sum == nQuestions)
        $('div#show-me-1').show();
      else if(sum == -nQuestions)
        $('div#show-me-3').show();
      else
        $('div#show-me-2').show();
    }
  });
});
```

I'm assuming each question is always going to have a "p" title, and as you can see, I'm using that title to know the number of questions. You can adapt that if you need it.

Here you have the working fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/m9xnng2e/

**EDITED:**

Apparently you need this behaviour with different groups of questions inside of your form. Here you have the "extended" version:

```
<form id="questions">

<fieldset>
    <p class="question-title">Question one...</p>
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <p class="question-title">Question two...</p>
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <p class="question-title">Question three...</p>
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="thirdq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <div class="show-me-1" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'Yes'</div>
    <div class="show-me-2" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are a combination of 'Yes' 'No' and 'Unsure'</div>
    <div class="show-me-3" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'No'</div>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
    <p class="question-title">Question one...</p>
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="firstq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <p class="question-title">Question two...</p>
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="1" />Yes
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="-1" />No
    <input name="secondq" type="radio" data-weight="0" />Unsure

    <div class="show-me-1" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'Yes'</div>
    <div class="show-me-2" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are a combination of 'Yes' 'No' and 'Unsure'</div>
    <div class="show-me-3" class="result" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'No'</div>
</fieldset>

</form>
```

***IMPORTANT: Notice that now the show divs have "class", instead of "id". You shouldn't have the same "id" in different elements!!***

And then just a few changes in the Javascript/jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

    var $thisFieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset');
    var nQuestions = $thisFieldset.find('p.question-title').length;
    var $checkedItems = $thisFieldset.find('input[type="radio"]:checked');

    if($checkedItems.length == nQuestions) {  // All answered

      var sum = 0;
      $checkedItems.each(function() {
          sum += Number($(this).data('weight'));
      });

      $thisFieldset.find('div.result').hide();
      if(sum == nQuestions)
        $thisFieldset.find('div.show-me-1').show();
      else if(sum == -nQuestions)
        $thisFieldset.find('div.show-me-3').show();
      else
        $thisFieldset.find('div.show-me-2').show();
    }
  });
});
```

I hope it helps

Comment: This is great - just what I was after. Thanks!

Comment: Question - This works perfectly when I have just one on the page but I need to have two (or more) and when there are multiples, the functionality doesn't work. Im assuming its because the script is waiting for all radio buttons to be selected. What do I need to change to make it only look for the radio buttons in a particular selection? (So I need two blocks of the above questions on the one page)

Comment: I worked out a solution. Pretty sure its not the right/best way to do it but it works.

Comment: I've edited the answer adding multi question group version. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

- Add 'id' for all 'yes' and 'no' check boxes so that we can take count when all "yes/no" buttons are checked.And display corresponding div(show-me-1/show-me-2) accordingly
- Add class for all, so that we can track if any one is checked.And if any combination of all 3 is checked show corresponding div(show-me-3)
- when one div is displayed hide all others. And initially keep all hidden

```html
  

     <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="question-1">
    <p>Question one...</p>
    <input class="yes" id="yes1" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
    <input class="no"  id="no1" name="test" type="radio" />No
    <input class="un"  id="un1" name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<form id="question-2">
    <p>Question two...</p>
    <input class="yes"  id="yes2" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
    <input class="no"  id="no2"  name="test" type="radio" />No
    <input class="un"  id="un2" name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<form id="question-3">
    <p>Question three...</p>
    <input class="yes"  id="yes3" name="test" type="radio" /> Yes
    <input class="no"  id="no3"  name="test" type="radio" />No
    <input class="un"  id="un3" name="test" type="radio" />Unsure
</form>
<div id="show-me-1" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'Yes'</div>
<div id="show-me-2" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are a combination of 'Yes' 'No' and 'Unsure'</div>
<div id="show-me-3" style="display:none; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 20px; background-color: #efefef;">Show this if all answers are 'No'</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#show-me-1').hide();
        $('#show-me-2').hide();
        $('#show-me-3').hide();


        $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {

            if ($('#yes1').is(":checked"))
            {
                if ($('#yes2').is(":checked"))
                {
                    if ($('#yes3').is(":checked"))
                    {
                        $('#show-me-1').show();
                        $('#show-me-2').hide();
                        $('#show-me-3').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('#show-me-1').hide();
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#show-me-1').hide();
                }
            }else{
                $('#show-me-1').hide();
            }

            if ($('#no1').is(":checked"))
            {
                if ($('#no2').is(":checked"))
                {
                    if ($('#no3').is(":checked"))
                    {
                        $('#show-me-3').show();
                        $('#show-me-1').hide();
                        $('#show-me-2').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('#show-me-3').hide();
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#show-me-3').hide();
                }
            }else{
                $('#show-me-3').hide();
            }

            if ($('.yes').is(":checked"))
            {
                if ($('.no').is(":checked"))
                {
                    if ($('.un').is(":checked"))
                    {
                        $('#show-me-2').show();
                        $('#show-me-1').hide();
                        $('#show-me-3').hide();
                    }else{
                        $('#show-me-2').hide();
                    }
                }else{
                    $('#show-me-2').hide();
                }
            }else{
                $('#show-me-2').hide();
            }

        });
    });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ajithmohan/hoL7gjz3/

Comment: add class and id for each radio button, and calculated the count at each click.

Comment: Add the info in your solution please, with all your steps to be concise.